# How to set the Tx power of Bluetooth in Linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth, transmission

I have been working with Linux for a year now, but there are still some aspects of Linux that I'm struggling to understand.

Currently, I am facing an issue related to setting the transmission power (tx power) of Bluetooth. I have attempted various methods and searched through multiple forums, but I have yet to find a solution.

Here are the steps I have taken so far:

- I used the `hciconfig` command to identify my Bluetooth device.
- Next, I attempted to change the tx power using the following command:

  ```
  sudo hciconfig hci0 inqtpl 10
  ```

To verify if the tx power had indeed changed to 10, I ran the command:

```
  sudo hciconfig hci0 inqtpl
```

The tx power remained the same as it was before the attempted change.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure your Bluetooth chip supports level 10?

Comment: Yes, even I tried with lower values till 1. The value is constant after setting Tx power that means it didn't change.

Comment: Philippos, I would greatly appreciate it if you could provide any suggestions or clues regarding this matter. Your input would be immensely helpful.